# Import json to html input fields with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a json like this from a url. (Example: http//www.somedomain.com/controller/json)

```
[{"id":"12","event":"LOGOUT SUCCESS","ip":"0.0.0.0","date":"2016.04.08 15:44"}]
```

I would like to import these values to an html file's form input fields with jQuery. The form is like this:

```
<input id="id" type="text" value="12">
<input id="event" type="text value="LOGOUT SUCCESS">
...
```

Is there any simple solution for this?

Comment: When you say "with a url" do you mean you made an ajax call and that is the response?

Comment: Also, does the form already exist in the html or are you wanting to create a form using that json?

Answer (score 2):

Since the `id` of each input field is the same as the `name` in each name/value pair, a `for..in` loop can do this very easily.

```
$.getJSON("http//www.somedomain.com/controller/json", function(json) {
    json = json[0]; //the object is in the first element of the wrapping array
    for (name in json)
        $("form").append('<input id="'+name+'" type="text" value="'+json[name]+'"/>');
});
```

If you wish to just set the values of an already existing form:

```
$.getJSON("http//www.somedomain.com/controller/json", function(json) {
    json = json[0];
    for (name in json)
        $("#"+name).val(json[name]);
});
```

Comment: I had to edit the answer because in testing I realized that the object is wrapped in an array, and so I had to add `json = json[0];`. Let me know if this answer works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Parse the JSON to an object. You can then iterate through it and create or set the input elements. Although you asked for it in the question, this is so trivial that there is little point in using jQuery for it ([You Might Not Need jQuery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)).

**If you wish to create the inputs:**

```js
var json = '[{"id":"12","event":"LOGOUT SUCCESS","ip":"0.0.0.0","date":"2016.04.08 15:44"}]',
    data = JSON.parse(json)[0];

for (var key in data) {
  if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    var i = document.createElement("input");
        i.setAttribute('type',"text");
        i.setAttribute('name',key);
        i.setAttribute('value',data[key]);
    document.body.appendChild(i); 
  }
}
```

**If you just wish to set the values:**

```js
var json = '[{"id":"12","event":"LOGOUT SUCCESS","ip":"0.0.0.0","date":"2016.04.08 15:44"}]',
    data = JSON.parse(json)[0];

for (var key in data) {
  if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    document.getElementsByName(key)[0].value = data[key];
    //or document.getElementsById("#"+key)[0].value = data[key];
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="id" value="" />
<input type="text" name="event" value="" />
<input type="text" name="ip" value="" />
<input type="text" name="date" value="" />
```

Comment: The form is already in the html. All it needs to do is load values into the already existing form.

Comment: @4castle Do we know this for sure or could the OP's question be interpreted in two ways?

Comment: You're right. It could be interpreted that way. But then you aren't using jQuery in your answer, even though the question asked for it and it would compact your code.

Comment: @4castle Agreed. The down vote is valid. I've improved my answer to better clarify my position on the avoidance of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You can unserialize your json :

```
json_string = "[{"id":"12","event":"LOGOUT SUCCESS","ip":"0.0.0.0","date":"2016.04.08 15:44"}]";
var arr_from_json = JSON.parse( json_string );
```

And then loop on the attributes :

```
$.each( arr_from_json, function(i, n){
 $("#"+i).attr("value",n);
});
```